# For Loop for stack columns per page

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around it.  Say you have 3 columns per page but the number counter organized by stack instead.  (They told me it is called Stack).  So, here's the example below if you're stumped by "Stack" definition.  I appreciate any help you can provide w/ the C# code.

The arrayIndex need to reflect the value in the 2 examples below.

// Example #1 --> 8 records
Page 1 -->  0, 3, 6
Page 2 -->  1, 4, 7
Page 3 -->  2, 5, null

// Example #2   --> 22 records
Page 1 --> 0, 8, 16
Page 2 --> 1, 9, 17
Page 3 --> 2, 10, 18
Page 4 --> 3, 11, 19
Page 5 --> 4, 12, 20
Page 6 --> 5, 13, 21
Page 7 --> 6, 14, null
Page 8 --> 7, 15, null

```
  var rowsPerPage = 3;
  var pageTotal = (21 / 3).ToInt();
  var arrayIndex = 0;

  for (var pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < pageTotal; pageIndex++)
  {
      var arrayIndexColumn1 = ((rowsPerPage * 0) * (pageIndex + 1));
      var arrayIndexColumn2 = ((rowsPerPage * 1) * (pageIndex + 1));
      var arrayIndexColumn3 = ((rowsPerPage * 2) * (pageIndex + 1));
  }
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Yea I couldn't get the arrayIndex to produce the value provided in the 2 examples.

Comment: So the output is entirely based on the number of records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not far. Basically `rowsPerPage` should be `pageTotal` in the formula.

```
int spResultRangeTotal = 22;
var rowsPerPage = 3;
var pageTotal = (int)Math.Ceiling(spResultRangeTotal / (double)rowsPerPage);

for (var pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < pageTotal; pageIndex++)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < rowsPerPage; row++)
    {
        int number = pageIndex+pageTotal*row;
        if (number  < spResultRangeTotal)
            Console.Write(number);
        else
            Console.Write("null");
        Console.Write( ", ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas said the problem is you've switched around your axis. You can do it pretty much exactly as you did before.  I've renamed the variables to better illustrate. Fiddle is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n0sUJI).

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var totalResults = 22;
        var columns = 3;
        var rowTotal = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalResults/(double)columns);
        
        for(int row = 0;row < rowTotal;++row)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{GetValue(row,0)}, {GetValue(row,1)}, {GetValue(row,2)}");
        }
        
        string GetValue(int row, int col)
        {
            var ret = rowTotal * col + row;
            return ret < totalResults ? ret.ToString() : "null";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one to play with.  You can change the number of columns.  I've used -1 to indicate "null" as that is probably easier to use.  Each row is stored in a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    var columnsPerPage = 3;
    var numberOfRecords = 22;
    var rowsTotal = (int)Math.Ceiling(numberOfRecords / (double)columnsPerPage);

    for (var pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < rowsTotal; pageIndex++)
    {
        List<int> values = new List<int>();
        for(int i=0; i<columnsPerPage; i++) {
          var curValue = pageIndex + (rowsTotal*i);
          values.Add((curValue < numberOfRecords) ? curValue : -1);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", values));
    }
  }
}
```

Output for 8:

```
0, 3, 6
1, 4, 7
2, 5, -1
```

Output for 22:

```
0, 8, 16
1, 9, 17
2, 10, 18
3, 11, 19
4, 12, 20
5, 13, 21
6, 14, -1
7, 15, -1
```